# C# Union/Order by com LINQ e Performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Imaginem a seguinte situação
existem 3 classes
classe A,
classe B,
classe C,
a classe A possui muitos classes B e muitos classes C.
a classe B possui muitos classes C.
a clsse C possui um campo datetime data.

```
public class A
{
  DBContext db = new ClassesContext();
  public IEnumerable<B> classesB{get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<C> classesC{get; set;}

  public IEnumerable<C> retornaTodasC()
  {
    var classes = ....
    return classes;
  }
}

public class B
{
 public IEnumerable<C> classesC{get; set;}
}
public class C
{
 public datetime Data;
}
```

como ficaria uma busca (feita pela classe A)ao banco de dados usando LINQ, order by, de todas as classes C da classe A e  das classes C de cada classe B dentro dessa mesma classe A, ordenado por data e armazenando todas as classes 3 em uma "var classes"?

agora imaginem que a classe A é instanciada mtas vezes, e utilizam muito esta busca, qual seria uma boa solução levando em consideração a "performance" neste caso?

Answer (score 3):

**Query**

Existem duas possibilidades. No titulo refere Union (isto é, sem elementos repetidos caso existam), portanto assumindo o uso do operador a query ficaria:

```
var classes = ClassesB.SelectMany(b => b.classesC)
                      .Union(ClassesC)
                      .OrderBy(c => c.Data);
```

No entanto, se desejar manter todos os resultados (repetidos incluidos) (como indica na pergunta, todas as classes de C em A e das classes C de cada classe B) a query ficaria:

```
var classes = ClassesB.SelectMany(b => b.classesC)
                      .Concat(ClassesC)
                      .OrderBy(c => c.Data);
```

Em termos de impacto na performance, a primeira *query* tem um maior impacto dado que o operador `.Union()` vai percorrer a primeira lista, adicionar os elementos a uma lista auxiliar e de seguida percorrer a segunda lista e devolver todos os objectos que não se encontram na lista auxiliar.

Ja a segunda *query*, o `Concat()` apenas devolve os elementos de ambas as listas.

No fim vai depender se precisa dos elementos repetidos na lista final.

**Utilização da busca**

Relativamente ao uso da busca múltiplas vezes depende da frequência de actualização dos dados de origem. Poderia explicar mais detalhadamente como é que a classe A será alterada? Se irá à base de dados a cada acesso ou vai guardar os valores lidos da primeira vez em memória?